# Function clogb2() generated by vivado can't synthesize with loop limit error

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I'm trying to design an AXI_master peripheral with vivado. I used the axi peripheral generator in vivado menu and modified the vhdl code generated.

In vhdl code there is a function clogb2 declared with following code:

```
function clogb2 (bit_depth : integer) return integer is
    variable depth  : integer := bit_depth;
    variable count  : integer := 1;
begin
  for clogb2 in 1 to bit_depth loop  -- Works for up to 32 bit integers
    if (bit_depth <= 2) then
      count := 1;
    else
      if(depth <= 1) then
          count := count;
        else
          depth := depth / 2;
        count := count + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
  end loop;
  return(count);
end;
```

This works in simulation (GHDL) but fail in synthesis with error :

> [Synth 8-403] loop limit (65538) exceeded

I tried to increase loop limit in vivado with following tcl command :

```
set_param synth.elaboration.rodinMoreOptions "rt::set_parameter max_loop_limit <X>"
```

As explained [here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/58823.html), but vivado synthesize with an infinite time and never finish.
Do you know how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try a different path. Although floating point is not supported in logic (although support is increasing), it is allowed for internal calculations and such. (By at least Xilinx and Altera/Intel).

Try this:

```
use ieee.math_real.all;

function ceillog2(input : positive) return natural is
begin
    return integer(ceil(log2(real(input))));
end function;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try constraining the range of the input, for example:

```
function clogb2 (bit_depth : integer range 1 to 32) return integer is
```

Also, if Vivado is generating code that it cannot compile, this is a bug that you should report on the Xilinx forums.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution that work by rewriting the function with a big case :

```
function clogb2 (bit_depth : integer) return integer is
 begin
     case bit_depth is
         when 0 to 2             => return( 1);
         when (2** 1)+1 to 2** 2 => return( 2);
         when (2** 2)+1 to 2** 3 => return( 3);
         when (2** 3)+1 to 2** 4 => return( 4);
         when (2** 4)+1 to 2** 5 => return( 5);
         when (2** 5)+1 to 2** 6 => return( 6);
         when (2** 6)+1 to 2** 7 => return( 7);
         when (2** 7)+1 to 2** 8 => return( 8);
         when (2** 8)+1 to 2** 9 => return( 9);
         when (2** 9)+1 to 2**10 => return(10);
         when (2**10)+1 to 2**11 => return(11);
         when (2**11)+1 to 2**12 => return(12);
         when (2**12)+1 to 2**13 => return(13);
         when (2**13)+1 to 2**14 => return(14);
         when (2**14)+1 to 2**15 => return(15);
         when (2**15)+1 to 2**16 => return(16);
         when (2**16)+1 to 2**17 => return(17);
         when (2**17)+1 to 2**18 => return(18);
         when (2**18)+1 to 2**19 => return(19);
         when (2**19)+1 to 2**20 => return(20);
         when (2**20)+1 to 2**21 => return(21);
         when (2**21)+1 to 2**22 => return(22);
         when (2**22)+1 to 2**23 => return(23);
         when (2**23)+1 to 2**24 => return(24);
         when (2**24)+1 to 2**25 => return(25);
         when (2**25)+1 to 2**26 => return(26);
         when (2**26)+1 to 2**27 => return(27);
         when (2**27)+1 to 2**28 => return(28);
         when (2**28)+1 to 2**29 => return(29);
         when (2**29)+1 to 2**30 => return(30);
         when (2**30)+1 to (2**31)-1 => return(31);
         when others => return(0);
     end case;
 end;
```

With this weird code structure, that works in synthesis and simulation.

Comment: Did you look at either of the other answers? This is not an elegant solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

This recursive version synthesises:

```
function clogb2 (bit_depth : integer) return integer is 
  begin
    if bit_depth <= 1 then
      return 0;
    else
      return clogb2(bit_depth / 2) + 1;
    end if;
  end function clogb2;
```

You can use it to dimension other things, eg

```
entity counter is
  generic (max_count : POSITIVE);
  port (clock, reset : in  std_logic;
        Q            : out std_logic_vector(clogb2(max_count) downto 0)  
       );
end;
```

or you can use it as combinational logic:

```
process (I)
begin
  O <= clogb2(I);
end process;
```

BTW: you would be better using an integer subtype for your input:

```
function clogb2 (bit_depth : positive) return integer is 
--                               ^
--                               |
```

Comment: But do you like the answer? `clog2bee.vhdl:20:9:@0ms:(report note): clogb2 (112000) = 16`. This particular value requires a binary length of 17 to describe. The function call should also have a positive range. A negative integer  or zero value will never reach bit_depth =  1. Depending on the tool there will be a recursion limit, it will just loop or you'll run out of calling stack.

Comment: @user1155120 I do like the answer: log2 of 112000 is 16 in integer maths. The original function did use a positive input - I changed the interface and function name to match the question.

Comment: 2 ** 16 is 65536. The ceiling (as in the accepted answer's ceillog2) to hold a value of 112000 is 2 ** 17 (131072) where 11200 falls between. Your function provides a floor value. In your defense the question could have shown a use for the function call.

Comment: An integer type with an unspecified initial value will default to integer'LEFT which is a negative number. It isn't sufficient to show the use of a positive subtype as an actual with a parameter typemark that allows a negative value. I personally found the simulator that spin loops doing recursive calls morally repugnant but not defined as an error or erroneous under the standard.